# Substract dates in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

Is there are any way to substaract dates in HQL. I just found how to substract days from date: http://www.hplsql.org/minus

But I need to substract miliseconds or dates but whet I trying to use it, i get `QuerySyntaxException`.

I need to do something like this:

```
h.createDate < 
    CASE 
        WHEN h.timeout IS NOT NULL 
            THEN current_timestamp() - h.timeout 
            ELSE :date 
    END
```

Can I do it using HQL?

Comment: HQL doesn't support very much date manipulation, partly because the underlying SQL database all handle dates so differently from each other.  If you can tolerate storing your dates as UNIX timestamps, then it would be easy to do any arithmetic on them.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen unfortunately I can't store dates as timestamps...

Answer (score 1):

HQL does not have this kind of date function.

So, if you would like to manipulate dates and still use JPQL/HQL queries, you need to look what the native date functions your database have and use them inside the HQL query.

Per example, using MySql you can use the `DATE_SUB` function to subtract days from a date.